# Change position of LibVLCSharp media player

Tags: wpf, libvlc, libvlcsharp

I'm using LibVLCSharp.WPF to record and play videos. I have some issue with changing video's position by forward and backwards.

First time click on Play button this method is called:

```
public void StartPlayback(TimeSpan fromPos, double playbackRate)
{
    _mediaPlayer.SetRate((float)playbackRate);
    SetPosition(fromPos);
    Timer.Start();
    _mediaPlayer.Play();
}
```

After changing video's position with `SetPosition` method by given timespan it should be play. This is my method to change position.

```
public void SetPosition(TimeSpan ts)
{
    TimeSpan absoluteTs = ts;
    if (ts < TimeSpan.Zero)
    {
        absoluteTs = ts.Duration();
    }
    _mediaPlayer.Position = (float)(absoluteTs.TotalMilliseconds / _mediaPlayer.Length);
}
```

But after changing position video is not playing at all and doesn't change frame. I don't quiet understand what I'm missing here.

Comment: NOTE: you could set the Time instead of Position (you wouldn't have to get the video length for that). Otherwise, could you have a look at the logs?

Comment: I tried to also, but still no result. Also I realize some error on logs.
`libdvbpsi error (PSI decoder): TS discontinuity (received 4, expected 3) for PID 32`